# unable to decrypt password protected pkcs8 key

Tags: openssl

I am unable to decrypt password protected `pkcs8` key using the below `openssl` command.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Command:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in keyname.pem -out labs.pem
```

Output:

```
Error decrypting key
 140471497754272:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong    tag:tasn_dec.c:1319:
140471497754272:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=X509_ALGOR
140471497754272:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:751:Field=pkeyalg, Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO
140471497754272:error:2306A065:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_item_decrypt_d2i:decode error:p12_decr.c:148:
```

Comment: Are you sure, that it is a PKCS#8 key and not a key in the openssl format? What does the PEM-header say?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
openssl pkcs8 -v1 PBE-SHA1-3DES -in C:\1.pem -out C:\1_decrypted.pem
```

This will try to decrypt your container with SHA1-3DES algorithms